# Command Line for Loop to Change Variables in File

Tags: linux, loops, for-loop, idl

I have a script that compiles and runs a piece of idl code. Looks like this,

```
arg1=$1

idl << EOF
.rnew testvalue_{arg1}.pro
testvalue_{arg1}.pro
EOF
```

I want to run a for loop from the command line is in which arg1 can take on different names. What I have so far is,

```
for arg1 in testvalue.sh; do arg1={'value1', 'value2'}; done
```

I don't think my logic is correct. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you need to place `$` before variable name so bash knows that it is replaced
Also you just need to give `testvalue.sh` value, because it is copied from `$1` to `$arg1`
But why I don't recommend creating new variables, just use `$1` two times
So the `testvalue.sh` is:

```
 idl << EOF
 .rnew testvalue_$1.pro
 testvalue_$1.pro
```

And the loop:

```
for arg in 'value1' 'value2'; do ./testvalue.sh $arg; done
```

Comment: @user3093032 at stackoverflow we say "Thank you" by accepting answer)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little hazy on the exact details of the question, but it sounds like you want to put 'value1' and 'value2' inside the list of values the for-loop iterates:

```
for arg1 in value1 value2
do
    idl <<EOF
    .rnew testvalue_${arg1}.pro
    testvalue_${arg1}.pro
EOF
done
```

Note that I've also changed {arg1} to ${arg1}, as the dollar sign is required to expand the variable.

A `for` loop in shell scripts will iterate over every value after the `in` keyword. In the example above it will set `arg1` to `value1`, then execute the contents of the loop, then move on and set `arg1` to `value2` and execute again.

You can also store the values in a variable:

```
values_to_test="value1 value2"

for arg1 in $values_to_test
do
    idl <<EOF
    .rnew testvalue_${arg1}.pro
    testvalue_${arg1}.pro
EOF
done
```

Bear in mind that this applies word splitting and path expansion to `values_to_test`, so you will need to ensure that none of the values contain question marks, square brackets, asterisks, spaces, tabs, or newlines.

If it worries you, you can disable path expansion (and thus allow use of question marks, square brackets and asterisks) by running `set -f` in the script before the loop runs.

Comment: Thanks so much! And for the detailed explanations. I've got it working now.